# Unmet peer dependency not getting solved Angular

Tags: angular, package.json

I cloned a git repository which I want to run on my PC, the first thing that I did was `npm install` but my application was not running even after installing packages. 
its my 3rd day I'm trying to run, but still invain, I read many posts regarding `packages.json`, `npm` usage `what are dependencies` etc and other material regarding this.
now when I list the packages there are some packages with `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` even though I explicitly installed them after my regular `npm insall` still they appear as `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` in my `npm list`  ?
how do I get rid of this, I already read alot of posts, but being a beginner, I've no idea what to do now.

```
D:\NewState\opticare>npm list -depth=0
opticare@0.0.0 D:\NewState\opticare
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/animations@5.2.11
+-- @angular/cli@1.7.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.2.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.2.11
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@5.2.11
+-- @angular/http@5.2.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@5.2.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.11
+-- @angular/router@5.2.11
+-- @auth0/angular-jwt@2.1.2
+-- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
+-- @swimlane/ngx-charts@7.4.0
+-- @types/datatables.net@1.10.18
+-- @types/jasmine@2.8.16
+-- @types/jquery@3.3.31
+-- @types/node@6.0.118
+-- @types/systemjs@0.20.7
+-- angular-archwizard@3.0.0
+-- angular-datatables@6.0.1
+-- angular2-csv@0.2.9
+-- angular2-spinner@1.0.10
+-- bcrypt-nodejs@0.0.3
+-- chalk@2.4.2
+-- chart.js@2.9.3
+-- codelyzer@4.5.0
+-- core-js@2.6.11
+-- cron@1.8.2
+-- datatables.net@1.10.20
+-- datatables.net-dt@1.10.20
+-- express@4.17.1
+-- file-saver@1.3.8
+-- googleapis@35.0.0
+-- http-errors@1.7.3
+-- install-peerdeps@2.0.1
+-- jasmine-core@2.8.0
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
+-- jodit-angular@1.0.86
+-- jquery@3.4.1
+-- jsonwebtoken@8.5.1
+-- jwt-decode@2.2.0
+-- karma@2.0.5
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
+-- lodash@4.17.15
+-- moment@2.24.0
+-- moment-timezone@0.5.27
+-- mongoose@5.8.9
+-- mongoose-paginate@5.0.3
+-- multer@1.4.2
+-- ng2-nouislider@1.8.2
+-- ngx-bootstrap@2.0.5
+-- ngx-chips@1.9.8
+-- ngx-toastr@6.5.0
+-- node-cron@1.2.1
+-- node-sass@4.13.1
+-- nodemailer@4.7.0
+-- nouislider@11.1.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.5.12
+-- shortid@2.2.15
+-- ts-helpers@1.1.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@^5.0.0
+-- twilio@3.39.3
+-- typescript@2.4.2
+-- xlsx@0.13.5
`-- zone.js@0.8.29

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/animations@^6.0.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@>=6.0.0, required by @auth0/angular-jwt@2.1.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^6.1.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^6.0.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0, required by angular2-csv@0.2.9
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^6.0.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@^6.0.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.1.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0, required by angular2-csv@0.2.9
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^6.1.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^6.0.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^6.0.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: tslint@^5.0.0, required by codelyzer@4.5.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@~2.7.1 || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || ~3.0.0 || >=3.0.0-dev || >=3.1.0-dev || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev, required by gulp-typescript@5.0.1

D:\NewState\opticare>
```

and here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "opticare",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ng build",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.4.0",
    "angular-archwizard": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "angular2-spinner": "^1.0.10",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cron": "^1.3.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "googleapis": "^35.0.0",
    "http-errors": "^1.6.3",
    "install-peerdeps": "^2.0.1",
    "jodit-angular": "^1.0.59",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.4",
    "mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.7",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.9.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^6.4.0",
    "node-cron": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "nouislider": "^11.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "twilio": "^3.19.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.13.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/systemjs": "^0.20.5",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: The Git repository you've cloned has lots of conflicting dependencies. I suggest you contact the developers of the Git repository regarding this issue or attempt to fix it yourself by updating the dependencies to the latest version. (EDIT: Is it this repository that I found on GitHub? https://github.com/newelljmn14/Opticare)

Comment: Open git bash [Give the project correct path]
then,
Run following cmd:
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ rm package-lock.json
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install
$ npm start

Comment: It looks like the owner of the original repository has not maintained the project since 2017. I suggest that you create a new Angular project instead and attempt to add back the dependencies.

Comment: @SandipBailkar It won't help - there are tons of conflicting dependencies as seen in the log. You **have** to fix the conflicting issues before your code can run properly.

Comment: is there anyway I can resolve it myself ?
the angular version of application is `5.2.11`

Comment: I already spent 2 days, but still unable to run this

Comment: @Edric no, this is not that repository that you linked.
Also can you please tell me how did you got to know about conflicting dependencies? or refer mein to any article ?
I just want to know, so that next time when I come across with this type of repository, I would know in advance and not waste my days

Comment: Please, can you help in this regard ? I've absolutely not idea what to do,

Answer (score 1):

Install the repositories that are `UNMET` one by one, `npm audit` runs automatically in background as soon as you install any package.
Make the version in your `package.json` according to your `npm audit`